# New deployment, have browser cache cleared the first time the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, deployment, browser-cache, web-deployment

The situation:

- Application deployed and in use.
- JavaScript / jQuery (in .js file) updates made.
- Application redeployed
- User does not see JavaScript changes unless they clear their cache.

This is presenting non-trivial issues.

Is there a way to have the cache cleared:

1. Automatically and
2. Just on the first load (cache as normal after that) when a new deployment is rolled out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a paraneter to the filename. Like: path/to/styles.css?deployed=20130424 and path/to/scripts.js?deployed=20130424

Comment: Thanks juuga. That can work, however, I would expect a simpler solution. This requires that the deployment script sets a value in some config file that is read when the page loads. I'll hold out for a potentially better solution before marking your answer as correct. Thanks very much.

Comment: @user1488103 Appending url arguments is a common practice for the so called *cache busting* (google that and you will find more information). Even [RequireJS has an option to define them](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs)...

Comment: You're welcome. You might be also able to work the cache with setting headers for the JS and CSS files. Expires and Last-modified could be what you are looking for (I can't give you an exact answer, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

use jawr, this will create hash  for each file based on changes(if file not changed that it will not create new hash for that file)  https://jawr.java.net/